# Insert PDO with Primary KEY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to get the primary id from the client table but i can't get it ..

Here is my source code

```
    if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO client  (client_name,client_owner,client_contact) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($client_name,$client_owner,$client_contact));
        // for teamviewer
        $sql1 = "SELECT client_id TOP 1 FROM client ORDER BY client_id desc";
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO teamviewer (client_id,tv1,tv2,tv3) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $q1 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
        $q1->execute(array($sql1,$teamviewerstore,$teamviewerserver,$teamviewerbackoffice));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("location: index.php");  
    }
```

I use this select query to get the top 1 from client id will be created

```
    $sql1 = "SELECT client_id TOP 1 FROM client ORDER BY client_id desc";
```

I want to insert the $sql1 to this query

```
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO teamviewer (client_id,tv1,tv2,tv3) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $q1 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
    $q1->execute(array($sql1,$teamviewerstore,$teamviewerserver,$teamviewerbackoffice));
```

Any kind of suggestion are much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: From what I can see, you're not retrieving the result from `$sql1`, instead you're just inserting the string as a value to `$sql2`

Comment: Yea but you dont actually execute the query you are using to get the client id !!!!!!!

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: I suggest you look [at the manual for `PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) Its easier than the query you are not running

Comment: sorry im just new to php ..

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? You're query will be quoted and escaped when bound. `TOP 1` won't work with `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql1 = "SELECT client_id FROM client ORDER BY client_id desc LIMIT 1";
$clientID = $pdo -> prepare($sql1);
$clientID -> execute();
$result = $clientID -> fetch();
$id = $result['client_id'];
```

Then use the `$id` to the `$sql2` as a value to the `client_id` column

Comment: I didn't bother checking whether the result has returned something. And you might notice that I used `prepare()` even though there is nothing to prepare, don't worry, it's just a habit of mine

Comment: Thank you .. but i got an error on the line with $clientID -> execute();

Comment: What error?Based from a comment in your post, `TOP 1` does not work with `mysql`, use `LIMIT 1` instead

Comment: Thanks sir @carl Jan it works now .. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @Carl, you're preparing the `$sql1` statement so it is preparing something

Comment: Well, it is true, but what I mean is that there are no parameterized queries in there haha